# Point DNS for domain name to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, networking, dns

I'm sure this has been asked a few times, but I can't seem to find an answer. I am hosting a website on Godaddy. I have another account that is hosting the domain.

On the hosting account we have a dedicated IP with a few subfolders. Is there any way to point the DNS to an actual folder? Can I do this with any domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point domain name to your dedicated IP, but then you can change the web-server configuration to redirect all domain traffic to one specific sub-folder.

Read virtual hosting with apache sever :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: So it's going to be a server side configuration. Thanks for that. I'll look at this tonight!

Comment: So I read over the instructions and it sounds like exactly what I need. However, with this being hosted on Godaddy, I don't have easy access to SSH. Is there any way to do this without connecting via SSH?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

Log in to your GoDaddy account and go to the "My Account" page.

**Step 2**

Click on "Hosting" on the left side of the page under "My Products," then click on "Manage Account" and choose "Domain Management" under "Settings."

**Step 3**

Click "Add Domain." Enter the new domain name in the field marked "Domain," and enter the sub-folder that will contain the site in the "Folder" field. Click "OK" to complete the process.